# What's the best way to avoid null using inside lambda using Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this piece of code and i'm trying to figure out what's the best way to avoid null pointer exception using Java 8?

```
promotion.forEach(item ->
    item.getDiscount().getPromotions().forEach(promotion -> {
        // logic code here
    })
);
```

Comment: Where is the potential NPE? What's the connection to lambdas?

Comment: Careful - You have two variables named `promotion` here.

Comment: You can use `Optional.ofNullable`

Comment: The class `Optional` was specifically included in the Java Platform Library to handle cases in which `null` values can occur in the streams.

Comment: Seems like this question can generalize to any use of iterators... it's not limited  to lambdas.

Comment: The best way is not to have null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
promotion.stream()
    .map(item->item.getDiscount()).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(discount->discount.getPromotions()).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(innerPromotion->{//logic code});
```

You can filter all the null elements out before you use them in the logic code so that only the non-null elements have the logic code run.

Comment: Is the .filter(discount - discount != null) necessary? Doesn't .map(discount->discount.getPromotions()) do the job?

Comment: If item.getDiscount() returned null then you'd get a NPE when doing .map(discount.getPromotions()) unless you filter out the null discount values first

Comment: I would argue that the Discount class should be designed to *never* return null from a collection method like getPromotions;  when there are zero promotions, always return an empty collection.

Comment: Perfect answer so that foreach doesn't throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to avoid NullPointerExceptions is to avoid null values. In your example, make sure all the methods never return null.

Instead of returning null you have several options:

- throw an exeption. For example if a method's input causes a division by zero you can throw an exception instead of returning null.
- return an empty Optional. For example a method returning String could be changed to return Optional<String>. When there is no String to return, you return Optional.empty()
- return an empty Collection (e.g. when the result type is a List, return an empty List if there are no results found, rather than returning null)
- return a custom result type, capable of reflecting the result. For example when doing validation you could return a ValidationResult representing success/failure and error messages instead of returning a null error message when there is no error

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking about something like [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) :

```
item.getDiscount().getPromotions().stream().forEach(promotion ->     
    Optional.ofNullable(promotion).ifPresent(p -> {
        // logic code 
    } )
);
```

EDIT : if `item.getDiscount()` may be null then you can try :

```
Optional.ofNullable(item.getDiscount()).ifPresent(d -> 
    d.getPromotions().stream().forEach(promotion ->     
        Optional.ofNullable(promotion).ifPresent(p -> {
            // logic code 
        } )
    )
);
```

Comment: on .getPromotions() it will raise NPE don't?